# Mixing normal and inline lists in one environment

Tags: lists, indentation, enumitem

I'm redoing my résumé and would like to produce a certain style of lists using [`enumitem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem), as shown in the image below.

If it isn't possible, it isn't the end of the world, but I'd really like it if [`enumitem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) could take care of all my formatting for me, while I could just focus on my content.

Basically, I want an inline list to be treated as one "item" in a normal itemized list.

Is it possible to produce the layout below strictly using [`enumitem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem)?

### MWE Image:

[image: image of MWE output]

### MWE Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}

\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{%
  , label      = \textbullet
  , leftmargin = *
  , nosep      = true
}
\setlist[itemize,1]{%
  , leftmargin = 0mm
}
\setlist[itemize,2]{%
  , label      = \textasteriskcentered
}

\begin{document}

\section*{Normal lists (via \texttt{enumitem})}
%
\begin{itemize}
  \item fruits:
        \begin{itemize}
          \item apple
          \item banana
          \item cherry
        \end{itemize}
  \item vegetables:
        \begin{itemize}
          \item asparagus
          \item broccoli
          \item celery
        \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\section*{Inline lists (via \texttt{enumitem})}
%
\begin{itemize}
  \item fruits
        \begin{itemize*}[after={{.}}, before=\unskip{: }, itemjoin={{; }}]
          \item apple
          \item banana
          \item cherry
        \end{itemize*}
  \item vegetables
        \begin{itemize*}[after={{.}}, before=\unskip{: }, itemjoin={{; }}]
          \item asparagus
          \item broccoli
          \item celery
        \end{itemize*}
\end{itemize}

\section*{Desired list (manual)}
%
\begin{itemize}
  \item fruits:
        \begin{itemize}
          \item apple; \textasteriskcentered{} banana; \textasteriskcentered{} cherry.
        \end{itemize}
  \item vegetables:
        \begin{itemize}
          \item asparagus; \textasteriskcentered{} broccoli; \textasteriskcentered{} celery.
        \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a personal environment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{%
  label      = \textbullet,
  leftmargin = *,
  nosep      = true,
}
\setlist[itemize,1]{%
  leftmargin = 0mm,
}
\setlist[itemize,2]{%
  label      = \textasteriskcentered,
}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{resitemize}
  {\ifnum\@listdepth=\z@
     \def\final@command{itemize}%
     \begin{itemize}
   \else
     \def\final@command{itemize*}%
     \begin{itemize*}[after=., before=\unskip:\\, itemjoin=;\space]
   \fi
  }
  {\expandafter\end\expandafter{\final@command}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section*{Normal lists}

\begin{resitemize}
  \item fruits
        \begin{resitemize}
          \item apple
          \item banana
          \item cherry
        \end{resitemize}
  \item vegetables
        \begin{resitemize}
          \item asparagus
          \item broccoli
          \item celery
        \end{resitemize}
\end{resitemize}

\end{document}
```

At level one it does `itemize`, at level two it does `itemize*` with the desired setup.

[image]